# Having troubles with Fancy zoom on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to use the plugin FancyZoom (for showing full images on clicking the thumbnails) from [here](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jquery-fancyzoom/).

I modified it a little bit to better suit my needs, but somehow it's not working in IE.

The exception it gives on IE is:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'css': object is null or undefined
jquery.fancyzoom.js, line 91 character 5
```

For quick reference, the code piece of javascript is:

```
function closeZoomBox(o){
 var oImgZoomBox = o.oImgZoomBox;
 o.oImgClose.remove();
 $('div',oImgZoomBox).remove();
 var endClose = function(){
   oImgZoomBox.empty().remove();
   o.imgSrc.css('opacity',1); // THROWING ERROR HERE
};
}
```

[I have my site hosted here](http://test.mmxhealthcare.com/screens/accredability/).

It would be really helpful if you can look into what wrong I am doing. (Or suggest me any other plugin which can suit my needs).

The problem is only with IE9. It works even for IE8, IE7.

I cannot start a bounty until 22 hours, but I promise I will award a bounty of 100 points, if anybody can help me out with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went through all the Javascript code and figured out the problem, which was in the file-names of the images. I was using `"registration pages.png"` (with a space) and it was somehow converting this file name to `"registration%20pages.png"` in the code and comparing it with the original filename. It was a lame error, but I think it was more in the way I was implementing.

Thanks people whoever invested their time.

Answer (score 3):

It says right on the plugin's homepage, "The shadow plugin works only for non ie browser, add it in the header of your html page and fancy zoom will display a shadow on the zoomed image."

Here's alternatives that work in IE: Shadowbox.js seems to meet your needs and works in "all major browsers" http://www.shadowbox-js.com/. Or, check out lightbox 2 at http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ "works on all modern browsers" and "Lightbox2 is open-source."

Comment: The plugin doesn't work in IE9. Not a problem with shadow. The image tries to start loading, but then stops.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use FancyZoom? Why not just use LightBox2?

Comment: The images I have are big, even bigger than desktop resolution. And it handles them perfectly and resizes them accordingly. Lightbox2 doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3's transitions - they are supported by MSIE 10 and much nicer - no need for javascript!

```
<style>
 img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 }
 img:target {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
 }
</style>
<a href="#img1"><img id="img1" src="./img.png" /></a>
<a href="#img2"><img id="img2" src="./img.png" /></a>
```

So easy :D

EDIT: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qp3J8/1/) is a link to jsFiddle.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want something like that. I found the plugin exactly satisfying my needs, but just not able to get it working on IE9 for some reason.